# How do you pan the nodes viewer?

Tags: node-editor

What's the hotkeys to pan the node viewer on Linux, it's not listed in the settings or the docs?

Tried every combination of Alt, Shift, Contrl and Left or Right mouse button in the nodes panel.

Comment: Hold middle mouse and drag?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I guess I should've said I'm on a laptop but couldn't find it under settings to customize it though.

Comment: Have you tried swiping with 2 fingers (with or without shift or alt)?

Comment: you should be able to see what's the shortcut and change it in the Preferences > Keymap > View 2D > Pan View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to emulate the middle mouse button, you can enable it from the settings in the *Input* pane.

After enabling the middle mouse button emulation, you should be able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> along with the left mouse button for panning the view.

[See here for mir information.](http://www.blenderhut.com/use-blender-without-middle-mouse-button-or-scroll-wheel/)